# Is there a schema for describing test questions in HTML?

Tags: schema.org

I'm building a site that will let users take practice tests and I was wondering... Is there some schema to define the question and answers that will make it easier for search engines to understand my content.

I'm trying to do everything possible to make the site rank well with search engines and I've been told schema's are a great way to do that.

I looked at the ones on schema.org but I can't find anything similar. Is there any other resource I could use?

Comment: Is it similar to a q&a board like Stack Overflow (one question, several answers)? Or do you mean with "answers" a list of possible answers, like in multiple choice?

Comment: I mean like a list of possible answers (multiple choice) similar to an exam that you would take (e.g. the SAT's)

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest types would be [`Question`](http://schema.org/Question) and [`Answer`](http://schema.org/Answer). While they are probably primarily intended for Q&A sites (like Stack Overflow) or FAQs, their description doesn’t seem to exclude quizzes.

You could use the [`suggestedAnswer` property](http://schema.org/suggestedAnswer) to link from the Question to each possible Answer.